# Quantification and logical relations, shorthand notation $\forall/\exists x \in M...$

Tags: logic, model-theory, foundations

I know the following shorthand:
\begin{align*}
 \exists x \in M : P(x) & := \exists x ( x \in M \to P(x) ) \\
 \forall x \in M : P(x) & := \forall x ( x \in M \to P(x) ).
\end{align*}
Now for me it is obvious that
$$
 \forall x \in M : P(x) \equiv \neg \exists x \in M : \neg P(x).
$$
But also it holds that $\forall x : P(x) \equiv \neg \exists x : \neg P(x)$. So applying I get
\begin{align*}
 \forall x \in M : P(x) & \equiv \forall x ( x \in M \to P(x) ) \\
                        & \equiv \neg \exists x ( \neg( x \notin M \lor P(x))) \\
                        & \equiv \neg \exists x : ( x \in M \land \neg P(x) ) \\
\end{align*}
and otherwise
$$
 \forall x \in M : P(x) \equiv \neg \exists x \in M : \neg P(x) 
                        \equiv \neg \exists x ( x \in M \to \neg P(x) ).
$$
So concluding
$$
 \neg \exists x : ( x \in M \land \neg P(x) ) \equiv \neg \exists x ( x \in M \to \neg P(x) ).
$$
or
$$
 \exists x : ( x \in M \land \neg P(x) ) \equiv \exists x ( x \in M \to \neg P(x) ).
$$
which obviously is not equivalent. But how to explain?

Comment: Your shorthand for $\exists{x\in M}$ isn't right.  You need to have $\exists{x\in M}{:}P(x)$ defined as $\exists{x}(x\in M \wedge P(x))$.

Comment: ok, if so then it is wrong in my textbook and also on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification

Comment: Not so Stefan. Look more carefully.

Comment: by using this shorthand I even get more contradictions results, then $\forall x \in M : P(x) \equiv \forall x ( x \in M \land P(x) ) \equiv \neg \exists ( x \notin M \lor \neg P(x))$ and $\forall x \in M : P(x) \equiv \neg \exists x \in M : \neg P(x) \equiv \neg \exists ( x\in M \land \neg P(x))$, concluding $\exists x ( x \in M \lor \neg P(x)) \equiv \exists x (x \in M \land \neg P(x) )$ which obviously is not the same...

Comment: ...Which is one reason among many why the shorthand in the first displayed line of your post is wrong.

Comment: ah yes sorry thought you meant in both definitions...

Comment: Your shorthand is at least extremely confusing, which is reason enough to avoid it even if it can be somehow interpreted so it makes sense.  Are you using := (sorry, I don't know the $\LaTeX$ for it) as you are using $\equiv$ below?  If so, your first displayed equation seems to be false, because if $M$ is the empty set, the LHS is false and the RHS is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct definitions are schematically $$(\forall F x)G x \leftrightarrow \forall x (F x \to G x),$$ and $$(\exists F x)G x \leftrightarrow \exists x (F x \wedge G x),$$ where the variable $x$ is a free variable in $F$ and $G$.

Note carefully that the definition of universal quantification has a conditional statement in its definition, but the definition of existential quantification has a conjunction in its definition. In your specific cases the definitions would read $$\forall x[x \in M \to P(x)],$$ and $$\exists x[x \in M \wedge P(x)],$$ respectively.